# Two following elements in a list

Tags: python, list, loops

I am preparing for my final exam and I had a task where I have to check if there are two `"F"` next to each other. For example, the `"F"` in `["F","F","I"]`.

I made a code but it gave me an error (list index out of range).
Tried to find solution but could not.

```
ekf = 0
for i in range(len(data)):
    if data[i] == "F" and data[i+1] == "F":
        ekf = ekf+1
print(ekf, "-szer/-szor volt egymas utan ket fej.")
```

Comment: Do you fully understand what list index out of range means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for the last `i`, it is equal to `len(data) - 1`. Then `i+1 = len(data)`, which is out of bounds.

Consider

```
for i in range(1, len(data)):
    if data[i-1] == "F" and data[i] == "F":
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is a string, and your values are characters, note that you can also use the expression

`"FF" in data`

to check if the string `data` contains the substring `FF`.

Furthermore, you can use `data.count("FF")` to count the non-overlapping occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [**zip**](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#all) and [**all**](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#all), this isn't advantageous for checking two adjacent elements but it will be if you have to check a `n` elements next to each other and they are numbers or something:

```
import unittest


def two_adjacent_chars(letters: str, char: str) -> bool:
    for adjacent_chars in zip(letters, letters[1:]):
        if all(c == char for c in adjacent_chars):
            return True
    return False


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    '''Test Cases'''
    test_cases = [
        (["A", "B", "C", "F", "F", "D"], 'F', True),
        (["A", "B", "C", "C", "F"], 'F', False)
    ]

    def test_two_adjacent_chars(self) -> None:
        for [letters, char, expected] in self.test_cases:
            actual = two_adjacent_chars(letters, char)
            self.assertEqual(actual, expected)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```